# Maintaining order of mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection that will have many documents (maybe millions). When a user inserts a new document, I would like to have a field that maintains the "order" of the data that I can index. For example, if one field is time, in this format "1352392957.46516", if I have three documents, the first with time: 1352392957.46516 and the second with time: 1352392957.48516 (20ms later) and the third with 1352392957.49516 (10ms later) I would like to have an another field where the first document would have 0, and the second would be 1, the third 2 and so on.

The reason I want this is so that I can index that field, then when I do a find I can do an efficient $mod operation to down sample the data. So for example, if I have a million docs, and I only want 1000 of them evenly spaced, I could do a  $mod [1000, 0] on the integer field.

The reason I could not do that on the Time field is because they may not be perfectly spaced, or might be all even or odd so the mod would not work. So the separate integer field would keep the order in a linearly increasing fashion.

Also, you should be able to insert documents anywhere in the collection, so all subsequent fields would need to be updated.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Or would I have to implement this? Or is there a more efficient way of doing what I am describing?

Comment: This http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field should pretty much answer your question.

Comment: Why do you need to "insert" a document? Updating "all subsequent integers" sounds painful. Is there some reason you can't add to the end? Are the integer supposed to be a sort-order too?

Comment: The integer should be sort order since that's the only way I can think of to efficiently down sample the data. I would like for users to be able to insert old data that may have a timestamp earlier than the end.

Comment: Also, I agree it sounds painful, but for my application, I would rather have slower inserts and fast queries. However, if there is a better way to do what I am talking about, that would be great too.

Comment: Or how about this, is there a way to access the sorted index and do a $mod on that? Like if I keep my data unsorted and do something like this, db.data.find().sort({time:1}) but then somehow do a mod on this result using the order of the returned results? This does not work, but something like this: db.data.find().sort({time:1}).find({index: {$mod: [1000,0]}})

Answer (score 1):

It is well beyond "slower inserts" if you are updating several million documents for a single insert - this approach makes your entire collection the active working set. Similarly, in order to do the `$mod` comparison with a key value, you will have to compare every key value in the index.

Given your requirement for a sorted sampling order, I'm not sure there is a more efficient [preaggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/) approach you can take.

I would use [`skip()` and `limit()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D) to fetch a random document.  The `skip()` command will be scanning from the beginning of the index to skip over unwanted documents each time, but if you have enough RAM to keep the index in memory the performance should be acceptable:

```
// Add an index on time field
db.data.ensureIndex({'time':1})

// Count number of documents
var dc = db.data.count()

// Iterate and sample every 1000 docs
var i = 0; var sampleSize = 1000; var results = [];
while (i < dc) {
    results.push(db.data.find().sort({time:1}).skip(i).limit(1)[0]);
    i += sampleSize;
}

// Result array of sampled docs
printjson(results);
```

Comment: I think this might work for me, I was planning on caching the results of the query anyway. I would only have to rerun this type of query when 1000 (in this example) more entries have been added.

Comment: I ended up using map reduce. The above answer proved to be too slow. Now what I do is use the scope option for mapReduce and keep an external count and index. I sort the inputs using sort and build a results document with an array of only the documents I want. This seems to be really quick.